# When getting injections after a dog bite, what to expect?

Tags: food-safety, injections, rabies, animal-bites

When a street dog bites a human, is it always necessary to take 5 doses [day 0, 3, 7, 14, 28] of injections? For a small bite, could one injection be enough?

If a person was bitten again, would they need a different course of treatment with less injections?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I counted 5 question marks. Isn't that a bit much when you should only ask one question? I recommend you to split them up into at least three questions, this question right now is in danger of being closed as to broad!

Comment: I have to agree this is too many questions. Please edit it to be a single question. You can post the others as separate questions if you wish.