# Which is the best injection after dog bite in india

Tags: injections

Which is the best injection  after dog bite in india

In India, is Rabipur the preferred injection?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't recommend one manufacturer's vaccine over the other.

Comment: @Lucky Unless it's the exact same formulation, I beg to differ. We can in fact talk about the differences in particular vaccines, however I think this question should be closed as a "shopping question."

Comment: @AtlLED Differences yes, but to recommend "the best one" - I wouldn't dare to do that, especially not over the internet. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of several brands of rabies vaccine available in India. A list can be found [here](http://www.medlineindia.com/vaccines/rabies_vaccine.htm). It wouldn't be appropriate for anyone allergic to eggs since it is cultured in eggs. Otherwise, it should be perfectly fine and is on the lower end of the cost scale.

Probably only a pharmaceuticals distributor in India could say whether it's the "preferred" brand, but it is a major brand from a reputable manufacturer. It should be completely adequate to protect the patient.

Comment: Thanks , please check [link1](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/11858/when-getting-injections-after-a-dog-bite-what-to-expect) & [link2](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/11864/is-there-any-food-restrictions-after-dog-bite)